# Как определить тип предложения?

Tags: синтаксис

> **Если ему не нужна была моя помощь, то к чему он мне позвонил?**

Пытаюсь определить тип предложения.
*"Если"*— сигнализирует мне на условное. Но: неужели "то к чему он мне позвонил"— главное к "Если ему не нужна была моя помощь"? Или: "то к чему он мне позвонил"— это следствие от условия? Запуталась...

Answer (score 3):

Это не условное придаточное, это сопоставительное со значением антонимии:

Ему не нужна была моя помощь,**(а)** к чему **же** он мне позвонил?

Есть и уступительный оттенок: несмотря на то,что ему не нужна была моя помощь,  он мне позвонил.

Части такого сложного предложения семантически равно­правны, форма придаточной лишь отмечается союзом; сами же отношения близки к сочинительным, выражаемым с по­мощью союзов а, же.

Тем не менее союз  если...то является подчинительны­м, и он  оформляет сложноподчиненное предложение.  Союз "если...то" нужно рассматривать как омоним условного если (то), причем в сопоставительном сою­зе "то" является обязательным элементом, а в условном — факультативным коррелятом (соотносительным словом).

Answer (score 3):

> ***Если ему не нужна была моя помощь, то к чему он мне позвонил?***

[**"Русская грамматика"**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2999-3025.html#3017) подобные предложения относит к предложениям с  НЕСОБСТВЕННО-УСЛОВНЫМ ЗНАЧЕНИЕМ:

> ***ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ С НЕСОБСТВЕННО-УСЛОВНЫМ ЗНАЧЕНИЕМ***
>
> **§ 3017.** В предложениях с союзом *если* и его синонимами (см. § 3000) условное значение может ослабляться или утрачиваться совсем...
>
> <...>
>
> **§ 3025.** Особый вид семантического осложнения представляют предложения с союзом *если*, в которых главная часть, оформленная как
>   вопрос, содержит позитивную информацию о реальном факте, ставящем под
>   сомнение или опровергающем истинность, достоверность утверждаемого в
>   придаточной части.
>
> *Если действительно, как она говорит, она нечаянно зацепила рукавом
>   и рассыпала, то зачем же выскочил из комнаты такой красный и
>   взволнованный Николай Сергеич?* (Чех.); *Зачем же вы скрылись, если вы
>   не убивали?* (Чех.); *Если ты счастлив, О чем же ты плачешь, Милый мой
>   гость?* (Блок); *Если твой Кирилл так тебя любит, то как он может жить
>   с тобой врозь?* (Фед.); *Что ж ты взялся писать о нем и срамить его,
>   если он не сильно виноват?* (Нилин).
>
> Такие построения основаны на столкновении двух версий: согласно
>   одной, названной в придаточной части, сообщаемое соответствует
>   действительности; согласно другой, принадлежащей говорящему,
>   достоверность этой информации может быть оспорена на основании
>   несоответствия ситуаций. Такая семантика согласуется с исходным,
>   гипотетическим значением союза *если*, который в этих условиях может
>   быть заменен союзом *раз* (но не союзом *когда*).

Answer (score 2):

Это **особый семантический  подтип условных отношений**, которые связны с темой **логического обоснования.**

В них используются двухместные союзы (ЕСЛИ...ТО, ЕСЛИ...ЗНАЧИТ и др.).

Пример 1.  Схема "факт-вывод", **соответствие** ситуаций): **Если он не уезжает, значит, ему здесь нравится.**

2) Пример 2: В первой (условной) части делается предположение, а во второй (главной) части дается вывод о  несоответствии этого предположения факту.

**Если ему не нужна была моя помощь, то к чему он мне позвонил?**  Если ему  нужна была моя помощь, то почему он мне не позвонил? Здесь умозаключение выражено **вопросом о несоответствии ситуаций**.

Материал взят из учебника "Синтаксис современного русского языка".

Comment: Отношения - может быть, но придаточное не условное.

Comment: Я ориентируюсь на  учебник.  Тема: СПП с придаточными условия; подтема: частные случаи (семантические подтипы) придаточных условия.  И почему не условия? Вот самое простое наблюдение: Если солнце садится в облака, значит, завтра будет дождь. Разве это не придаточное условное? Но ведь оно тоже построено по схеме "факт - вывод".

Comment: Здесь-то условия:будет дождь, если увидим, что солнце садится в облака, а вот то, что ему не нужна помощь ,- не условие звонка, а ,наоборот, противоречит логике.

Comment: Какая разница, в любом случае это тема логического обоснования.  Здесь схема такая:  факт (условие) -  умозаключение в виде  вопроса о несоответствии. Если солнце село в облака, то почему сегодня нет дождя? Если ему здесь нравится, то почему он тогда уехал?

Answer (score 2):

Anonym, попробую сказать всё более простыми словами.

Сначала о значении, есть подозрение, что вы смысл не до конца поняли, потому и запутались.

В русском есть такая распространенная форма выражения мысли, наподобие силлогизма в логике.

***Если А, то (должно быть) В***

*Если ты сын своих родителей, то должен следовать их советам* 
(побудительная эмфаза, вывод: ты должен [следовать]).

Или в варианте с вопросом.

***Если А, то (почему/зачем/как могло/etc) В?!***
Здесь А и В - оба реальные, более того любое из них может быть уже реализовавшимся или состоявшиеся событием, но не вместе. Из этого автор делает вывод, что событие А не имело места или сомневается в этом.

*[На улице стоит хорошая погода]  - Если стоит хорошая погода, то почему все идут с зонтиками?*
(вывод: погода плохая)

*Если Сократ человек, то почему он бессмертен?*
(вывод: Сократ смертен)

*Если ты вегетарианец, то зачем покупаешь мясо?*
(тут просто недоумение)

*Если ты не спал, то как мог не услышать шум в соседней комнате?*
(аналогично, сомнение или вовсе выражение недоверия собеседнику)

Можно сказать и так, что "если" здесь выражает не условие, а исходное утверждение, имеет значение близкое к "поскольку" и выражает, таким образом, посыл для рассуждения, относясь не к одной части фразы, а как бы ко всему утверждению.

Для формы с вопроса такие предложения легко отличить по вопросительному слову во второй части. Утвердительная форма сложнее, она она не отличается от формы условного предложения, отличия только в том, что "Если" заменяется по смыслу на "поскольку". Но такие "утвердительные" предложения (судя по всему) всё-таки менее частые, не запутаетесь, надеюсь.

Если это всё понятно, то вы сами ответите на свой вопрос. ***Предложение ваше, по форме являясь условным или очень на него похожим, по сути выражает иную мысль, сопоставление, причину-следствие, одновременную или совместную (не)реализуемость***. Предложение такое в разных условиях называют  "сопоставительным" или "несобственно-условным" (как в других ответах, и то и другое правильно, только под разными углами зрения).

Но что хорошо, такие предложения у студентов-иностранцев обычно не вызывают затруднений понимания.

Comment: спасибо Вам большое, я на самом деле поняла! : ) можно еще вопрос? Ваш пример: "Если ты вегетарианец, то зачем покупаешь мясо?" Вы тронули тему, которая меня интересует тоже: пункт про сомнение, которое Вы упомянули. например мы выражаем модальность (здесь сомнение) через субхунтив; какими средствами выражает русский человек сомнение в этом примере? это интонация? или что-то другое? каким сигналом Вы даете собеседнику понять, что сомневаетесь что он вегетарианец?

Comment: *мы выражаем модальность (здесь сомнение) через субхунтив* - subjuctive? Ну как таковое "сослагательное наклонение" грамматисты в русском выделяют. Сылки уже давали. Но у меня-то все примеры на одну грамматическую форму (можно назвать "несобственно-условное"), вот через неё это сомнение и выражено. Русский просто не задумывается над подобными "сигналами". Может, со стороны и виден какой-то "сигнал", это для русского сама эта фраза, постановка вопроса, служит сигналом для выражения "модальности" (если это можно так назвать.

Comment: Я совершенно не уверен, что её однозначно поймут как сомнение, может как недоумении - или вообще воспримут как обиду... Но предполагается, что адресат этой фразы увидит в ней противоречие - и пояснит, что его либо не так поняли, либо мясо для кошки... Ну мало ли чего там было. Это понимание важно при полемике, научной особенно, но уверяю еще раз, иностранцы такие вещи понимаю легко. Менталитет у европейцев в общем-то одинаков. Вот с китайцами - да были у меня затруднения. Приходилось на английский переходить...

Comment: Я вот сейчас еще раз подумал... В общем-то четыре моих фразы ни грамматически, но интонационно, ни даже контекстно ничем друг от друга не отличаются.  Не знаю, откуда в них появляются эти оттенки смысла. Для меня это естественно, наверное и для любого русского... Может только степень реальности-ирреальность в обеих частях разная. Но если кто и исследовал этот вопрос, то в сугубо академическом ключе. Тут я вам не помощник. Вам известно английское  "If you're so smart, why aren't you rich?" Ну вот тот же случай, почти пословный перевод. Какие еще "сигналы"?